# Insert into two related tables (one to many) in Postgres using sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables with syntax as follows,

```
class Attribute_Values(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'attribute_values '

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('identities.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.JSON)

    def __init__(self, id, name, value):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Attribute_Values {self.id}>"


class Identities(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'identities'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(db.Text)

    user_data = db.relationship(Attribute_Values, backref='identities')

    def __init__(self, uuid):
        self.uuid = uuid

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Identities {self.id}>"
```

I have json document like,

```
{
'name' : {'cn' : 'abc' , 'sn' : 'nbg'},
'email' : 'abc@gmail.com',
.......
}
```

this entire json is one identity. I have to create UUID for each such document. The insert operation should result in the following data.

*Identities*

### id  | uuid

### 1    | created_uuid

*Attribute_Values*

### id  | name | value

### 1    |name  | {'cn' : 'abc' , 'sn' : 'nbg'}

### 1    |email | 'abc@gmail.com'

if you notice "id" is same for all attributes.
I tried to do something like this,

```
uuid_obj = uuid.uuid4().hex
for key, val in data.items():
    v = Attribute_Values(name=key, value=val)
    i = Identities(uuid=key, user_data=[v])
    tenant_session.add(i)
tenant_session.commit()
```

The issue in the above code is there should be only one entry for an identity in "Identities" table and it should be "uuid" generated here `uuid_obj = uuid.uuid4().hex`.  Because of the relation between two tables and are in a loop there are multiple entries created in Identities table. What would be solution for this?

Comment: The attributes primary key must be unique.  You should have the FK as a separate column.

Comment: both id and name are primary keys, why will that matter

Comment: Maybe you want to create a composite primary key from `(id, name)`?  A table's primary key must be either a single column or a composite key comprised of multiple columns, such that the resulting combination is always unique.

Comment: yes, it is composite primary key and its unique

Comment: My bad, it seems sqlalchemy is clever enough to automatically create a composite primary key if more than one is defined.  However your new edit doesn't match the code in the models (`affiliation` is not defined).

Comment: yes, affiliation attribute is not there i will remove it.

Comment: The issue was there was a space next to table name. I fixed it,  but if you notice i need to use uuid created in this line of code instead of 'key' ```Identities(uuid=key, user_data=[v])```, but because its a loop, i will get unique constraint error.  How do i solve this issue